# Service Response - use static method to create object in class code or create new object in controller? C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have `ServiceResponse` class:

```
public class ServiceResponse
{
    public List<string> Errors { get; set; }
    public bool Succeeded { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }

    public ServiceResponse() { }  

    public ServiceResponse(object result, List<string> errors, bool success)
    {
        Errors = errors;
        Data = result;
        Succeeded = success;
    }

    public static ServiceResponse Success(object result)
    {
        return new ServiceResponse(result, new(), true);
    }

    public static ServiceResponse Failure(List<string> errors)
    {
        return new ServiceResponse(new(), errors, false);
    }
}
```

And in my `controllers` I would call it:

```
 List<string> errors = new List<string>();

 try
 {
     return ServiceResponse.Success(await Mediator.Send(request));
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     errors.Add(ex.Message);
     return ServiceResponse.Failure(errors);
 }
```

I thought that this is neater solution than creating `ServiceResponse` object in controllers, but could this make problems if 2 people call for same controller, and is there chance that person A  get `ServiceResponse` from person B?

Comment: I think this should work just fine although I question why you don't make the function more dynamic. You could probably return whether it has succeeded or failed withing the service, then also handle the error there as to reduce the amount of try catches you wil have to manually write

Comment: But, I would write try catch in handlers then, right?

Comment: Depending on if you want to have optional lower level exception handling. If all you want the try catch to handle is adding the exceptions to `errors` list and then return a failure. I would place them in the service since the way you handle exceptions would technically be the same at every implementation. if you want additional exception handling you could keep your error handling rather the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there chance that person A get ServiceResponse from person B

No. While static member variables are shared across threads, the local variables of a static method are not. In your case the variables accessed in your static methods are all local, so they are safe.